# Resolving maximum request length exeeded error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, runtime-error

I am trying to upload files that are 6mb in size.
The web config is set as follows:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

I keep getting this error :
Maximum request length exceeded.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum request length exceeded.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so basically I figured that in my case even when editing the webconfig file and its maximum content length, it doesn't really work if you do not set your IIS settings correctly.

To do this:

1. go on the specific website you want to edit in IIS
2. select configuration Editor
3. set the section to - system.web/httpRuntime
4. set the MaxRequestLength in kilobytes. You can use this tool to make the conversion from kb to mb and vice versa easier https://www.unitconverters.net/data-storage/kb-to-mb.htm
5. Don't forget to click on apply in the right tab in IIS.
6. Retry and hope for the best :)

Comment: Strange that this would work over mike's answer.  It's basically doing the same thing, just through a different mechanism.  There must have been a typo or some other problem with your file that this approach circumvented.

Answer (score 2):

In **machine.config** 4MB is set as default, but you can override it in you **web.config** file.

Try adding this:

```
<configuration>  
    <system.web>
       <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
    </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: when adding it to the server an error 505 appears. I don't think this works in my case

Comment: Which .net framwork are you targetting?

Comment: @Burdy, have you introduced a syntax error in your config file?  Perhaps `system.web` or `httpRuntime` appears twice?  You may need to tweak the posted markup to fit your case.

Comment: @mike framework 4.6

Comment: @Burdy Indeed check what Twab Wakil said. Make also sure you are within <configuration></configuration>.  You can also add targeted framework : targetFramework="4.6..." I will update my solution .

Answer (score 0):

Please set 'MaxRequestLength' property in httpRuntime section of web.config to a higher value. Please note that the unit for this property value is KB. The default is 4096 KB = 4 MB

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength?view=netframework-4.8